# Where/how do Snp 5.7 & 15 prove kāya in meditation context is rūpa-kāya by default?

Tags: pali, rupa, kaya

I read the following in [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/49852/254):

> Snp 5 is a great example in usage that proves kāya in meditation
> context is rūpa-kāya by default.
>
> https://notesonthedhamma.blogspot.com/2021/10/kn-snp-5-buddha-knew-about-ambiguities.html

[Snp 5.7](https://suttacentral.net/snp5.7/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=none&highlight=false&script=latin) says, per Sujato translation:

> “As a flame tossed by a gust of wind,”
>
> “Accī yathā vātavegena khittā,
>
> replied the Buddha,
>
> (upasīvāti bhagavā)
>
> “comes to an end beyond reckoning;
>
> Atthaṁ paleti na upeti saṅkhaṁ;
>
> so too, a sage freed from mental **phenomena**
>
> Evaṁ munī nāma**kāyā** vimutto,
>
> comes to an end beyond reckoning.”
>
> Atthaṁ paleti na upeti saṅkhaṁ”.
>
> I ask the Sakyan about knowledge for them;
>
> Ñāṇaṁ sakkānupucchāmi,
>
> how should one like that be guided?”
>
> kathaṁ neyyo tathāvidho”.

[Snp 5.15](https://suttacentral.net/snp5.15/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=none&highlight=false&script=latin) says, per Sujato translation:

> said Venerable Posāla [to the Buddha],
>
> (iccāyasmā posālo)
>
> Consider one who perceives the disappearance of **form**,
>
> Vibhūta**rūpa**saññissa,
>
> who has entirely given up **the body**,
>
> sabba**kāya**ppahāyino;
>
> and who **sees nothing** at all
>
> Ajjhattañca bahiddhā ca,
>
> internally and externally.
>
> **natthi** kiñcīti **passato**;
>
> .........
>
> “Viññāṇaṭṭhitiyo sabbā,
>
> said the Buddha,
>
> (posālāti bhagavā)
>
> “all the planes of consciousness.
>
> Abhijānaṁ tathāgato;
>
> And he knows this one who remains,
>
> Tiṭṭhantamenaṁ jānāti,
>
> committed to that as their final goal.
>
> Vimuttaṁ tapparāyaṇaṁ.
>
> Understanding that desire for rebirth [**coming to be**]
>
> **Ākiñcaññasambhavaṁ** ñatvā,
>
> **in the dimension of nothingness** is a fetter,
>
> Nandī saṁyojanaṁ iti;

Where/how do Snp 5.7 & 15 prove kāya in meditation context is rūpa-kāya by default?

Comment: Kaya is also a Sanskrit word. It means Body.

Answer (score -1):

explained right here clearly in the ref. you quoted in OP
https://notesonthedhamma.blogspot.com/2021/10/kn-snp-5-buddha-knew-about-ambiguities.html

There's also the standard satipaṭṭhāna formula, with 4 frames.
First frame is kāya (physical body).
third frame is citta (mind).
If kāya is a joker wildcard where it can mean either physical body, or mind, or both collection of physical and mental, then there's no coherent unambiguous contrast with third frame citta.

The LBT (later buddhist teachings) redefined kāya to be either collection of mental factors, or physical body, according to their agenda to redefine 4 jhānas as a frozen disembodied stupor.

In EBT (early buddhist teachings),  the Buddha speaks plainly and unambiguously.
MN 125 alone clears up most jhāna controversies.

https://lucid24.org/mn/main/mn125/index.html#125.3.10.3

The Buddha explicitly equates satipatthana with first jhāna here.

This means kāya must be a physical body in first jhāna, and kāya anupassana of satipatṭhāna must be a physical body, because everyone agrees you can do kāya anupassana (body contemplation) in all 4 postures.
If you can hear sounds and think in satipatthāna with a physical body,
then you can hear sounds and think (with vitakka and vicāra) in first jhāna because MN 125 explicitly equates satipaṭṭhāna and first jhāna.

This is unequivocal, incontrovertible, and simple to see, for those who are not blinded by dogma and delusion.

> edit, addition to comment that attainment of nothingness only has
> perception of 'nothingness', and no other perception:

Try reading MN 111, AN 9.36. All 7 perception attainments (4 jhanas + first 3 formless) can realize nrivana WHILE in those attainments. But let me guess, you're either going to use faulty logic, or you're going to claim MN 111 and AN 9.36 are fake suttas. You know what's fake? Anyone who has an incoherent interpretation of Dhamma becuase they throw out half of the suttas that don't agree with their wrong views on Dhamma.

Comment: Thank you, I flagged this as "not an answer". I cannot discern how this relates to the question. The question is about Snp 5.7 & 15.

Comment: what is your problem? why do you just spam sutta passages with faulty analaysis, without even reading and understanding other interpretations?  I flag you as a Dhamma spammer who should be permanently banned. Half of your stuff is reasonable, the other half is blind dogmatism.

Comment: @DhammaDhatu The referenced (hyperlinked) page is about Snp 5.7 etc. and seems to contain an answer to the question you asked.

Comment: I tried to  read the blog. The blog said: "The quoted and highlighted Snp 5.15 passage is describing one entering the nothingness attainment, where the mind is separating from the body, but the mind is still percipient, aware of itself and its objects." This comment in the blog sounds wrong. In the sphere of nothingness there is only one  perception & experience, namely, "there is nothing".

Comment: Try reading MN 111, AN 9.36. All 7 perception attainments (4 jhanas + first 3 formless) can realize nrivana WHILE in those attainments. But let me guess, you're either going to use faulty logic, or you're going to claim MN 111 and AN 9.36 are fake suttas. You know what's fake? Anyone who has an incoherent interpretation of Dhamma becuase they throw out half of the suttas that don't agree with their wrong views on Dhamma.

Answer (score -1):

I will offer a personal opinion about this however first provide a disclaimer: I do not regard the [Pārāyanavagga](https://suttacentral.net/snp-parayanavagga?view=normal&lang=en) as authoritative in Buddhism. The [Pārāyanavagga](https://suttacentral.net/snp-parayanavagga?view=normal&lang=en) are brief teachings or answers spoken to questions of non-Buddhist students of a certain Brahmin Guru.

In SN 5.7, the term 'nama-kaya' is found in the following exchange:

> “He who is passionless regarding all sense pleasures, Upasīva,” said
> the Gracious One, “who is depending on nothingness, having given up
> all else, intent on the highest freedom which still has perception— he
> will remain there without going away.”
>
> “If he remains there without going away for a great number of years,
> All-Seeing Visionary, will he become cool and free right there, or
> will the consciousness of such a one fall away?”
>
> “As a flame overthrown by the force of the wind, Upasīva,” said the
> Gracious One, “goes to rest and can no longer be discerned, just so
> the Sage free from the **mental body** goes to rest and can no longer be
> discerned.”
>
> “There is no **measure (pamāṇamatthi)** of the one who has come to rest, Upasīva,” said the Gracious One, “there is nothing by which they can speak of him, when everything has been completely removed, all the pathways for speech are also completely removed.”
>
> [Ānandajoti](https://suttacentral.net/snp5.7/en/anandajoti?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false)

The above verse is clearly about mental reckoning/mental description (pamāṇamatthi). This appears what 'nama-kaya' refers to.

> pamāṇa    -   m   -   atthi    c
>
> pamāṇa: measure; size; amount. (nt.)
>
> atthi: to be; to exist. (as + a + ti)

SN 5.15 refers to kaya below in respect to nothingness. Note: the words 'rupa' & 'kaya' below are not spoken by the Buddha but, instead, spoken by the Brahmin student Posāla.

> Consider one who perceives the disappearance of form (rupa), who has
> entirely given up (pahāyin; pajahati) the body (kaya), and who sees
> nothing at all

Now, to reach the sphere of nothingness (which the Buddha later mentions in his reply), we know many mental states must be given up, such as sensual desire, rapture, happiness, infinite consciousness & the like. Therefore, it seems 'rupa' above refers to physicality and 'kaya' above refers to the whole 'collection' of the aggregates, particularly the mental aggregates. Thus when "all kaya" is given up, all that remains is the perception of 'there is nothing'.

In summary, it seems Snp 5.7 & 15 do not prove kāya in meditation context is rūpa-kāya by default. Snp 5.7 & 15 are just brief verbal ramblings between some Brahmin students and the Buddha.

Comment: see my other anwers on this thread, which have been edited to address Dhamma Dhatu's wrong understanding of the formless attainments

Answer (score -1):

SN 47.42 Body dependent on food, 4 satipaṭṭhāna context, showing that kāya is physical body in contrast to citta.

http://notesonthedhamma.blogspot.com/2023/11/sn-4742-body-dependent-on-food-4.html

edit, addition:
  MN‍ 10ma 0.10 - kāya rūpa is physical body
https://lucid24.org/mn/main/mn010/ma/index.html#0.10

Theravada root commentary to MN 10 satipatthana sutta, states the body in satipatthana context is referring to a physical body, of anatomical parts like hair.

Non-physical (mental) nutriments are obviously not going to sustain hair, heart, liver, etc.

Some of you other users are going to need to step up and start upvoting my answers. Otherwise I'm just going to stop wasting my time partcipating on this platform, when Dhamma Dhatu just downvotes every one of my carefully research and correct answers, and then either gets his friends or uses his numerous fake accounts to upvote his wrong answers.

Comment: There are four types of 'food' in the Buddha's teaching: physical, intention, contact & consciousness. Also, SN 47.42 is a fake teaching, similar to  MN 10 because it uses terminology improperly. Thanissaro makes a footnote about SN 47.42.

Comment: How many "real" suttas are in your incoherent Dhamma? How can you expect to have any common understanding of Buddhism when you arbitrarily pick suttas that support your wrong interpretation of Dhamma and throw out all the others? And why would you expect all other Buddhists to agree wit your set of fake and real suttas?

Comment: Some of you other users are going to need to step up and start upvoting my answers. Otherwise I'm just going to stop wasting my time partcipating on this platform, when Dhamma Dhatu just downvotes every one of my carefully research and correct answers, and then either gets his friends or uses his numerous fake accounts to upvote his wrong answers.

Comment: I've been reluctant to upvote answers like this one, not because they're wrong, but because I haven't studied this as much as you have, and so I don't "know for myself" whether they're good answers. I suppose the same is true for other expert-level answers on this site -- i.e. that they don't get many upvotes, because there aren't many experts on the site who are able to confirm (or correct) them. I do find it interesting to read the answers though, they expose me to aspects of Buddhist doctrine which I didn't even know existed.

Comment: I think it's true that DD often downvotes answers for reasons of his own. Whenever I see a downvote I read it as, "DhammaDhatu didn't like this!" Perhaps you can comfortably ignore any single downvote.

Comment: Fair point, on witholding upvoting things we're not sure about.